# Sections in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a manual in which each section is formatted at the top in the following manner:

```
Section:  2.1
Title:  Employee Conduct
```

I would like to create a Table of Contents that looks like this:

```
2.1 Employee Conduct.................................5
2.2 Code of Ethics...................................7
2.3 Absences from Work...............................11
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please specify what document tool you are using. Microsoft Word? Open Office? What version? (Please state it in the question, and also tag accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't manually creating the Heading numbers, ie. 2.1, 2.2 yourself and you're letting Word create them, it should be a breeze.

Basically go to the word ribbon -> Reference -> Table of Contents menu -> select either Automatic Table 1 or 2.

If you are creating the headings manually, start converting them to the word Header styles by using a Multi-level list on the Home tab -> paragraph section of the ribbon.

Formatting the ToC does become tricky however and involves editing style templates and such, but that should come last :)

Comment: Yes, we are manually creating the Heading numbers.  How can you let Word create them?  The format is exactly how it's shown in the original question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This link here should help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/add-numbers-to-headings-HP005186047.aspx
Also, accept the answer I provided if you think my response was what you needed :)